# Android: Adding elevation to a widget

Tags: android, layout, widget

I am trying to add elevation to a widget layout. I placed it the android:elevation in the root layout, I also tried putting it in the child relative layout also.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_background"
    android:elevation="30dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget_bad_data_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widget_no_data_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/widget_1x1_icon_width_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/widget_1x1_icon_width_height"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/widget_1x1_margin_top"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/widget_no_data_icon"
            android:text="@string/widget"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/widget_1x1"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute,SpUsage" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `elevation` to your base container. To be able to see the elevation effect, set its margin to `30dp`.